# How to set different trigger attribute for multiple tooltip in the same Combochart

Tags: javascript, triggers, tooltip, stacked-chart

I have done a small graph with Google charts combochart combining 
a stacked bar chart with a line chart.

The tooltips appear on all stacks and points of the line chart triggered by
mouse actions: 'focus' (mouse on the target), 'selection' (on click) and 'both' both click and focus.

I wanted to have all tooltips from line chart appeared after a click, trigger: set to 'selection' and all tooltips from stacked bar chart after a focus on the zone, trigger: set to 'focus'. Is this possible with Google Charts to set different tooltip behaviour in the same chart? How do I develop this?

Play my example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/machesne/xf1kccdq/

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);

function drawStacked() {

    var tooltipdata = [["Apples detail: ","Tomatoes detail: ", "Oranges detail : ", "Strawberries detail : "],["Apples detail: ","Tomatoes detail: ", "Oranges detail : ", "Strawberries detail : "],["Apples detail: ","Tomatoes detail: ", "Oranges detail : ", "Strawberries detail : "]]
  var valuedata = [[50, 10, 15, 15, 90, 90],[50, 12, 15, 15, 92, 92],[60, 10, 15, 15, 100, 100]];

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Apples', { role: 'tooltip' }, 'Tomatoes', { role: 'tooltip' }, 'Orange', { role: 'tooltip' }, 'Strawberries', { role: 'tooltip' }, { role: 'annotation' }, 'Sum' , { role: 'tooltip' }],
    ['', valuedata[0][0], tooltipdata[0][0], valuedata[0][1], tooltipdata[0][1], valuedata[0][2], tooltipdata[0][2], valuedata[0][3], tooltipdata[0][3], valuedata[0][4],valuedata[0][5], tooltipdata[0][4]],
    ['', valuedata[1][0], tooltipdata[1][0], valuedata[1][1], tooltipdata[1][1], valuedata[1][2], tooltipdata[1][2], valuedata[1][3], tooltipdata[1][3], valuedata[1][4],valuedata[1][5], tooltipdata[1][4]],
    ['', valuedata[2][0], tooltipdata[2][0], valuedata[2][1], tooltipdata[2][1], valuedata[2][2], tooltipdata[2][2], valuedata[2][3], tooltipdata[2][3], valuedata[2][4],valuedata[2][5], tooltipdata[2][4]], ]);

  var options = {
    width: 1200,
    height: 1000,
    legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 2 },
    seriesType: 'bars',
    bar: { groupWidth: '90%' },
    isStacked: true,
    tooltip: { isHtml: true, trigger: 'both' },    // CSS styling affects only HTML tooltips.
    series: {4: {type: 'line', pointSize: 15 } }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Thanks a lot for your answers!